# Can't pass protected enum as parameter for static method

Tags: c#, access-modifiers, class-visibility

I've been updating the company's software and stumbled upon this problem. There's this enum that's protected and I want to pass a value from that enum as a parameter for a static method, but I can't cause I have no access to it even though both the method and the enum are in the same class.

Example:

```
Class SomeClass
{    
    protected enum Car
    {
        Id
    };

    public static void AMethod(Car enumValue)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This is an enum:" + enumValue.ToString());
    }  
}
```

I can't use this `Car enumValue` as parameter for `AMethod` cause I have no access to it.
Why can't I do this? I mean they're in the same class. Am I missing something?

Comment: That's not going to work.  either make the enum public or create a new one for this use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is not that your `SomeClass` can't see the enum.  The problem is your enum has a `protected` access modifier, and you're trying to use it in a `public` method (i.e. accessible *outside* your class).  You can't expose a `protected` type through a `public` member because methods in other classes can't see the enum when they're trying to call `AMMethod()`.

Depending on how you intend to use this class, you need to change either one or the other so the access modifiers match:

```
public enum Car
{
    Id
};

public static void AMethod(Car enumValue)
{
    MessageBox.Show("This is an enum:" + enumValue.ToString());
}
```

or:

```
protected enum Car
{
    Id
};

protected static void AMethod(Car enumValue)
{
    MessageBox.Show("This is an enum:" + enumValue.ToString());
}
```

The latter one will just prevent the compiler error, but it may be the case that you *want* `AMethod` to be public, so you should choose the former.